# conditional formatting based on values of a column

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

[image]

I have a table where i want to highlight values with a color only if the sign (+ve or -ve number) in cells A through C matches with the sign of the value present in the last column D.

Example, for 1st row, D has a negative value, hence only cells in A and C should be highlighted. Cell in Column B will NOT be highlighted since it has a positive value.

Is it possible to do it with conditional formatting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a rule based on the following formula:

```
=SIGN(A1)=SIGN($D1)
```

[image]